# Booting to Safe or Single User Mode brings up Windows 10 Recovery

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, single-user, safe-mode

As part of trying to repair my Macintosh HD boot volume I have tried to boot into Safe Mode as well as Single User mode.  However, when I boot the computer using either of the proper keypress combinations, after a short wait I get this screen.

[image: Windows Recovery screen. Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed. Error code: 0xc000000e You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media like a disc or USB device, contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.]

Running High Sierra on a pre-Metal Mac Mini.  I have used Bootcamp previously and a corruption of the Windows installation is what started this rabbit hole.  The primary macOS Volume does appear when I hold down the Option key at startup but DiskUtil and 'fsck' are having issues verifying/repairing it and it will not boot at this time.  Neither will the Bootcamp Windows 10 volume.  I did unplug the computer to reset the SMC with no change.

How can I properly start my Mac in macOS Safe mode or Single-User mode instead of Windows Recovery?

Comment: Have you though of installing an fresh copy of OS X (macOS) in the 75 GB of free space where Windows used to be? You could then boot the computer to something other than recovery mode.

Comment: No, I hadn't.  I've been trying to handle the drive itself with kid gloves, but I suppose adding another partition on the end to boot from is not worse than anything else I've been doing so far.  Just trying every measure to recover the primary partition.  However, the original question still stands - if I absolutely needed to boot to safe or single-user mode, I can't.

Comment: If your EFI partition has either an `EFI/Boot` or `EFI/Microsoft` folder, then either one or both of these folders can have files that could create the image you posted. This really irrelevant. IMO, the Mac booted Windows Recovery because the Mac could not find a way to boot into safe or single-user mode. In other words, your macOS boot partition is trashed.

Comment: Very grateful for your patience and input.  Generated another partition and have Catalina installed on it.  (Odd, since I've been using High Sierra on my non-Metal-compatible system, but that's what it chose.)  Strangely, it found and mounted the errant partition as read-only, but that could make recovering the files significantly easier.  Going to pick up an external 1TB.  Not sure if I should make a Time Machine backup of it (to then restore from after reformatting), make a disk image file, or some other tool to literally copy the file structure.  Suggestions welcome.

Comment: What model year is your Mac mini? You should be able to get the model year from `About this Mac` on the menu bar. Will the external drive be a HDD or SSD? Do you know if the internal drive is a HDD or SSD?

Comment: Late 2012.  I bought a 1TB WD Easyport external (I believe it's an SSD?) as a Time Machine for my 2008 iMac (now deceased) and it served me well and was very inexpensive, so I was aiming to pick up another.  I believe the Mini has an HDD.

Comment: The reason I asked is this. I have a 2013 iMac with a 1 TB internal HDD. The computer worked adequately until I installed Catalina, which requires APFS. As it turns out, APFS does not work well with HDDs. I purchased a Samsung T7 SSD and installed Catalina on this external drive. There was a noticeable increase in performance over using the internal HDD. (Although, a Samsung T5 SSD should work just as well at a lower cost.) You Mac mini has the same USB 3.0 ports as my 2013 iMac.

Comment: I still use the internal HDD to store files, but boot from the external SSD. I have Windows 10 installed on the internal HDD.  Also, your Mac does support Catalina. See [macOS Catalina is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222).

Comment: Ah! I didn't recall seeing it on the list before.  I did notice that while the original partition is HFS+, the Catalina partition is indeed APFS.  As to the original sub-question, do you think I would have better results making a Time Machine backup of the damaged partition, a disk image, or using some third party software to copy the files and file structure to the external drive? The intent is to reformat and then restore.

Comment: If I have enough space is to copy my personal files to an external drive, I usually backup to an external drive, erase the internal drive, reinstall all software and copy back my personal files. I am not much of a Time Machine user since most of my personal files are in the cloud. I have used disk images when space is limited and I want to use compression. You might want to ask a new question to see what others might think.